# Lua class getting overwritten

Tags: oop, lua

So, I have this lua class (really a metatable) that is getting overwritten by one of it's children. Here is the code that makes the class:

```lua
--// Class
local Lexer = {
    Text = "",
    Pos = nil,
    CC = nil
}

--// Initializer
function Lexer.new(Text, Fn)
    -- Set metatable
    self = setmetatable({}, Lexer)

    -- Set variables
    self.Text = Text
    self.Pos = POS.new(0, 0, 0, Fn, Text)
    self.CC = nil
    self:Advance()

    -- Return
    return self
end
```

And here is the code for the POS module, which I am including:

```lua
--// Make the module
local Position = {
  Idx = 0,
  Line = 0,
  Col = 0,
  Fn = "",
  Ftxt = ""
}

--// Constructor
function Position.new(Idx, Line, Col, Fn, Ftxt)
  -- Set metatable
  self = setmetatable({}, Position)

  -- Set variables
  self.Idx  = Idx
  self.Line = Line
  self.Col  = Col
  self.Fn   = Fn
  self.Ftxt = Ftxt

  -- Return self
  return self
end
```

I have a .__index method in both of them. Help is appreciated!
Oh, and, POS is defined like:
`local POS = require("lib/position")`

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by `overwritten by one of it's children` you may need to explain what you expect to happen with the presented code, maybe an example of how you use these classes and what you expect vs what you got. also if that is your complete file for `Position` it would not work how you expect in `POS = require("lib/position")` you do not have `return Position` at the end of the file

Comment: I do actually have return position at the end of the code, I just forgot to copy it over. And, when I print out all of the indices of the Lexer class, I get the children of the Position class. When I change the type of the Pos object, it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self` is not defined and therefore you use the global `self` as a variable. Since you call the constructor of `Pos` while initializing `Lexer` it will cause errors. Prefix both `self` with `local`.

`self` is only automatically defined if using the `:` syntax, e.g. `Lexer:new()` and `function Lexer:new(Text, Fn)`.